# Image classification from "Imagery" basemap ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, imagery

I'm trying to reclassify the coast of France and Spain into rocky or sandy categories. So far, I've been drawing polygons around the different patches, but want to try using image classification to speed up the process.  Is there a way I can use the World_Imagery basemap as a normal raster which I can then use in image classification?

There was a similar question where the only answer was to "Export Map", but this would take as long as doing all the polygons by hand.

Comment: If you can link to that similar question, that would help provide context and additional information for people to answer :)

Comment: Have you seen the [Shoreline vector dataset](http://shoreline.noaa.gov/data/datasheets/wvs.html)? It may help you automate the extraction of imagery, just an idea...

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't perform imagery analysis on built-in basemaps.

That's said, you could use freely-available Landsat data, which you can download from [Earth Explorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov). Landsat collects multispectral data with a 30m resolution for the whole world every 16 days.

Comment: Alternatively you could zoom in to desired resolution, screenshot, autogeoreference the screenshots, mosaic, and classify using them. I suspect it would contravene ESRI's user agreements though. In addition the Imagery basemap is just that, visual sepctrum imagery. You wouldn't have the added benefit of multispectral analysis so classification would be less accurate.